# Google spreadsheet query multiple tables

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I will simplify my task a bit, but the gist of it should be clear.

I have a google spreadsheet document. For reasons, I have to use this platform and not excel or anything else.

On one page, I have a table with various products. Each product has a name and a price. There aren't supposed to be too many of those.

```
name    price
prod1   100
prod2   150
prod3   50
```

On the second sheet I have, let's call it orders, where each order occupies a row, it has a number, and then a column for each of the products with a quantity of that product.
Again, for reasons, I would like to keep that structure.

```
order   prod1   prod2   prod3   cost
1       2               1       ?
2               1               ?
3       1       1               ?
4       1       3       1       ?
```

Task: to calculate the sum cost of each order. So we need to look at how many products of each type is there, and then look at the other table to determine the cost of each item, and calculate the sum

How can I do that in google spreadsheets? In SQL I would simply use Join function, but Query() doesn't have this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **H2** and drag down

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE($E$1:$G$1), $A$2:$B, 2, 0) * TRANSPOSE(E2:G2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
I also found a bit simpler method:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE($H3:$P3),Parts!$C$4:$C$12)
```

To work properly it assumes that the items are ordered in the same manner in both tables, which is exactly what I got